# Process for prediction and interpretation for custom linear regression model?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, prediction

Let's say you want to build a custom linear model.  For parameter estimation, we can do MLE, which can be solved using gradient descent.

To determine our coefficients, we can do bootstrap resampling.  Here we assume our observed data is the population and we build a bootstrap distribution for our coefficients.  If 0 falls in between some interval, maybe the 95% HDI of the bootstrap distribution, than the coefficient is not significantly different from 0.   The parameter point prediction can just be the mean of our bootstrap distribution.

For prediction, we can once again build a bootstrap distribution of our prediction.  The mean of that distribution is our point prediction, and the 95% interval can be our confidence interval.

I have a few questions:

- Would you say my understanding of creating custom linear models correct?
- How would you assess the biasedness/unbiasedness of our coefficients and predictions?
- Is there a way to construct a prediction interval?

Comment: *The mean of that distribution is our point prediction, and the 95% interval can be our confidence interval*: did you mean *prediction interval*? If so, does it not answer your third question?

Comment: Custom linear model in what way, a custom loss function?

Comment: @RichardHardy  I thought the confidence interval is the 95% range for the expected mean value while prediction interval is the 95% range for possible predicted values.  Since our point prediction is usually the mean i.e. (E[Y | X]), then the sampling distribution of it should only give us the confidence interval.  I think we need to factor in the variance of our assumed distribution itself if we want the prediction interval but I am not sure.

Comment: @Dave Custom and more relaxed assumptions such as a different distribution for Y | X, non iid observations, so yes, custom loss function.  I am just looking for ways to bypass conventional assumptions.  If something strongly fits the assumptions of a GLM, I will use it.  But if I have to transform a bunch of data just to force my data to fit a pre-existing model, maybe there's a way to just use computational methods to obtain a result.  And if prediction and the value of b0/b1 coefficients are all that matter, I think computational methods may be a better use of time.

Comment: @confused, thanks, got your point.